Python searchable QComboBox
I am wondering if anybody have idea how to use QComboBox or any other tools
what I am trying to do is creating a searchbox with a dropdown result but since the database is too big, I am doing the search in the server thus returning only top 30 result.
• I tried using lineedit and completer but it wont allow me to scroll down
• also using lineEdit I cant get which signal to use when it's selected like combobox index change
• I also need to use QStandardItemModel because I have hidden value I want to get (ID) and it's different from text shown
• so I'm thinking of using QComboBox, set it to editable, connect it with function

    # Initialize the QComboBox as editable
    self.ui.comboBox_sku.setEditable(True)
    self.ui.comboBox_sku.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.perform_search)
    self.ui.comboBox_sku.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_sku_selected)


but this causes everytime we write on the combobox it immediately change the lineedit to 1st choice and not allowing us to write the next character
anybody have any idea or suggestion ?
thanks
ps: tried using qcompleter with combobox but it cause us having 2 data on the completer and combobox because we need to work with hidden value

QSqlQueryModel.

QSqlQueryModel are quite hard to set up connection, I've read but dont understand much.

The QtSql classes are very easy to use and will provide the best solution for your use case. There are many simple examples on SO (e.g. here and here), and also many basic tutorials available elsewhere (e.g. Handling SQL Databases With PyQt: The Basics). If you're willing to put a little effort into learning the Qt APIs, creating a searchable combo-box with a database model is not a difficult problem to solve.

Im using mariadb (mysql) what connection should I use ?

As I said: there are many examples on SO - all you need to do is search. For example: see this answer. If you're on Windows, you'll also need to install the mariadb connector and copy its dll to your Qt installation (see this question).

@AlbertSan 1. "I tried using lineedit and completer but it wont allow me to scroll down": that shouldn't happen, as by default it shows a popup QListView that does provide scroll. 2. the phrase "using lineEdit I cant get which signal to use when it's selected like combobox index change" is unclear, please explain what you mean. 3. "I need to use QStandardItemModel because I have hidden value I want to get (ID) and it's different from text shown" is also unclear, as all models provide the ability to use roles, and delegates can also show something that is different than the DisplayRole. »

@AlbertSan »We cannot help you if you only provide vague explanations of your attempts (we cannot know what was wrong with them) and insufficient code that uses functions we know nothing about (perform_search + on_sku_selected). That's why it's important to almost always provide an appropriate [mre] (which does not mean the full code, please read that link carefully). Still, what suggested by ekhumoro is quite appropriate, and your motivation for not using QtSql isn't very convincing: working around the issues you mention may be much harder than learning to set a proper connection.
